# Is the expression of my descendants or my future generations correct?

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to say my descendants or my future generations. If not what word can substitue for them? Thanks.

Comment: What's the context?  The correct phrase depends on what you're trying to say...

Comment: I mean,I think that "Descendants" is a word often used in some historical context, like Indians' descendants or Scottish settlers' descendants. I' not sure wether's weird to say my descendants.

Answer (score 1):

"My future generations" doesn't really make any sense. You could say "future generations of my family", but that could be taken to include descendants of those other than your immediate family.

"Descendents" refers to people who are directly descended from you. There isn't always a need to say "future descendants", as you may already have multiple generations of descendants (children, grandchildren etc).

However, if you are referring to possible future unborn descendants, then "**future descendants**" is fine.